# Create correct .jar file from .java file

Tags: java, jar

My goal is create .jar file from .java files and then create .exe file for Windows. But I can't create even correct .jar file.

Hello! I'm new in Java. Can you help me please? I tried to solve the problem for all day long yesterday :(

I use InteliJ Idea. I've created project with 2 classes: Main.java and WS.java.

[I've used corretto in InteliJ Idea](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ltqVn.jpg)

I can compilate my program in it. It can work correctly. I can compilate it in cmd. I've created .jar file but it doesn't working.

[Process of the program compilation and creation of the jar file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CuFBb.jpg)

I've used JDK corretto-21 to create .jar file via cmd. But I've got fail

[Can't create .jar file using corretto-21](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qb5no.jpg)

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.20348.2113]
(c) Корпорация Майкрософт (Microsoft Corporation). Все права защищены.

C:\Users\Admin\IdeaProjects\WebSocketProject\src>"C:\Users\Admin\.jdks\corretto-21.0.1\bin\java.exe" -version
openjdk version "21.0.1" 2023-10-17 LTS
OpenJDK Runtime Environment Corretto-21.0.1.12.1 (build 21.0.1+12-LTS)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM Corretto-21.0.1.12.1 (build 21.0.1+12-LTS, mixed mode, sharing)

C:\Users\Admin\IdeaProjects\WebSocketProject\src>"C:\Users\Admin\.jdks\corretto-21.0.1\bin\javac.exe" Main.java

C:\Users\Admin\IdeaProjects\WebSocketProject\src>"C:\Users\Admin\.jdks\corretto-21.0.1\bin\java.exe" Main
Socket: hi, client! Your ip is 213.139.212.17:63057
My program is working via using coretto-21
You: My program is working via using coretto-21
Socket: My program is working via using coretto-21
END
You: END

C:\Users\Admin\IdeaProjects\WebSocketProject\src>"C:\Users\Admin\.jdks\corretto-21.0.1\bin\java.exe" jar cfe app.jar Main Main.class
Error: Could not find or load main class jar
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: jar

C:\Users\Admin\IdeaProjects\WebSocketProject\src>"C:\Users\Admin\.jdks\corretto-21.0.1\bin\javac.exe" jar cfe app.jar Main Main.class
error: invalid flag: Main.class
Usage: javac <options> <source files>
use --help for a list of possible options

C:\Users\Admin\IdeaProjects\WebSocketProject\src>
```

Main.java have got the next view:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        WS ws = new WS();
        try {
            new Thread(ws::receiveAndPrintMessages).start();
            // Отправка сообщений из консоли
            ws.sendMessages();

        } catch (Exception ex) {
            System.out.println("Error: " + ex.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The program for building a jar file is `jar.exe`. You don't pass `jar` as a parameter to `java.exe`.

Comment: Add all information as text not as image

Answer (score 1):

Assume You have two .java files Main.java and WS.java

What you need todo:

1. Change working directory

   ```bash
   cd <path to your .java files>
   ```
2. Add JDK to PATH variable

   ```bash
   $env:Path += ";C:\Users\Admin\.jdks\corretto-21.0.1\bin"
   ```
3. Build JAR

   ```bash
   javac.exe .\Main.java .\WS.java
   jar.exe cfe app.jar Main .\Main.class .\WS.class
   java.exe -jar .\app.jar
   ```

For any external JAR dependencies, provide them with a `-classpath` option

If you want to build from Idea, consider using [Gradle](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/gradle.html) or [Maven](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/maven-support.html) instead. It will simplify build steps and dependency management for you

Answer (score 0):

I've added WS.class to jar-archive after the creation of the jar-file and it's working now!

[WS.class in jar-archive](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HJPD4.jpg)

You can create a jar file with 2 classes ( Main.java and WS.java ) using the next command:

```
jar cfe app2.jar Main Main.class WS.class
```

[click](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SL7oR.jpg)

But how can we create a correct jar file via IntelliJ Idea?
I've built it using Artifact building. And it's not correct!

Comment: You should create separate question for Intellij IDEA build